# Stack allocation to process and its occupancy by the data segment

Tags: memory-management, process, operating-system

Sorry if the questions are dumb, but they are really confusing me!
According to elf standard the binary is divided into segments like text segment (containing code and RO data) and data segment (containing RW & BSS) which is loaded into memory when the program is executed and process is created, with the segments providing information for environment preparation for process execution.
The question is, how it is decided that how much stack to allocate to process, when i am not providing stack size during process creation?
Also, using the data segment we can determine how much memory the process requires (for global variables) but once this memory is allocated how mapping of variables is done with the address space inside this allocated memory?
Lastly, is there any relation of this with scatter loading? which i think is not the case as scatter loading is done when image is to be loaded into memory and once control is passed to OS, the memory to be allocated to executable or applications is take care off by the OS itself!
I know these are too many questions, but any help will be greatly appreciated.
If u can provide any reference books or links where i can study in detail about this, that is also appreciated.
Thanks a tonne! :)

Answer (score 0):

`The question is, how it is decided that how much stack to allocate to process, when i am not providing stack size during process creation?`

When a new process created, `execve()` system call is used to load the new program as process image into memory from the current running process image. Which mean [execve](http://linux.die.net/man/2/execve) when new program is loaded replaces older `.text`, `.data` segments, `heap` and reset the `stack`. Now ELF executable file is mapped into memory address space making stack space getting initialized with environment array and the argument array to `main()`.

In [do_execve_common](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.11.2/fs/exec.c#L1459)() procedure call under subroutine [bprm_mm_init](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.11.2/fs/exec.c#L1515)() handles tasks such as,

1. New instance of `mm_struct` to manage process address space using call to [mm_alloc](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+*/fs/exec.c#L364)().
2. Initialize this instance with [init_new_context](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+*/fs/exec.c#L369)().
3. [bprm_mm_init](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+*/fs/exec.c#L247)() initializes stack.
4. [search_binary_handler](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+*/fs/exec.c#L1371)() routine searches for suitable [binary format](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+*/include/linux/binfmts.h#L66) i.e **load_binary**, **load_shlib** to load programs or dynamic libraries respectively. Followed by mapping memory to virtual address space and making process ready to run when scheduler identifies the process.

   Therefore, stack memory finally looks like below, which will appear to `main()` routine at start of the execution. Now and then each environment of a subset of function calls, including parameters and local variables are stored or pushed in stack memory zone dynamically when the calls happen.

   ```
   -----------------
   |                 | <--- Top of the Stack
   | environmental   | 
   | variables and   |
   | the other       |
   | parameters to   |
   | main()          |
    _________________  <--- Stack Pointer
   |                 |                
   |  Stack Space    |
   |                 |
   ```

`Also, using the data segment we can determine how much memory the process requires (for global variables) but once this memory is allocated how mapping of variables is done with the address space inside this allocated memory?`

Let try figuring out how variables are mapped to different parts of memory segments by debugging a simple `C` program as follows,

```
/* File Name: elf.c : Demonstrating Global variables  */
#include <stdio.h>
int add_numbers(void);           
int value1 = 10;        // Global Initialized: .data section 
int value2;             // Global Initialized: .bss section

int add_numbers(void)
{
    int result;         // Local Uninitialized: Stack section
    result = value1 + value2;
    return result;
}

int main(void)
{
    int final_result;   // Local Uninitialized: Stack section
    value2 = 20;
    final_result = add_numbers();
    printf("The sum of %d + %d is %d\n",
        value1, value2, final_result);
}
```

Using `readelf` to display `.data` section header as below,

```
    $readelf -a elf
    ...
    Section Headers:
    [26] .data             PROGBITS         00000000006c2060  000c2060
       00000000000016b0  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     32
    [27] .bss              NOBITS           00000000006c3720  000c3710
       0000000000002bc8  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     32
    ...
    $readelf -x 26 elf
    Hex dump of section '.data':
    0x006c2060 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
    0x006c2070 0a000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
    ...
```

Let's use GDB to look at what these section contain,

```
   (gdb) disassemble 0x006c2060
   Dump of assembler code for function `data_start`:
   0x00000000006c2060 <+0>: add    %al,(%rax)
   0x00000000006c2062 <+2>: add    %al,(%rax)
   0x00000000006c2064 <+4>: add    %al,(%rax)
   0x00000000006c2066 <+6>: add    %al,(%rax)
   End of assembler dump.
```

The above first address of `.data` section refers to `data_start` subroutine.

```
   (gdb) disassemble 0x006c2070
   Dump of assembler code for function `value1`:
   0x00000000006c2070 <+0>: or     (%rax),%al
   0x00000000006c2072 <+2>: add    %al,(%rax) 
   End of assembler dump.
   ....
```

The above disassemble dumps address of global variable `value1` initialized to
10. But we don't see global uninitialized variable `value2` in next addresses.

Let's look at printing the address of `value2`,

```
   (gdb) p &value2 
   $1 = (int *) 0x6c5eb0
   (gdb) info symbol 0x6c5eb0
   value2 in section **.bss**
   (gdb) disassemble 0x6c5eb0 
   Dump of assembler code for function `value2`:
   0x00000000006c5eb0 <+0>: add    %al,(%rax)
   0x00000000006c5eb2 <+2>: add    %al,(%rax)
   End of assembler dump.
```

Tada! Disassembling reference pointer of `value2` revels that the variable is stored in `.bss` section. This explains how the uninitialized global variables mapped to process memory space.

`Lastly, is there any relation of this with scatter loading?`

No.